# How do I fix black lines (edges) showing in Render Preview

Tags: octane-render-engine

I'm runnning Octane2022_Blender3.5 (3.4.1), though I think this was happening in vanilla Blender as well.  [image]

[image]

The black lines are "bleeding through" from the solid or wireframe display mode.  In other words, if I switch display modes, the black lines are the two lines that you see on either side of the window.

(The lines are displaced in this image because I'm using a fisheye lens.  The second image shows the same black lines with a normal lens.)

Does anybody know what is causing this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels like you have double edges there, try to check your geometry and delete intersecting edges if you have them.
[image: I moved this edge so you can better understand what i mean]
[image: Edge you need to delete]

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem!  I'm still curious why it would "leak" through into the render preview window like that, but I don't need to know.

Comment: @loosenut Blender sometimes does not know how to render overlapping geometry, especially double faces in the same location can cause problems because it cannot decide which face is in front/visible. This can result in black artifacts.

Comment: @loosenut Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, the answer section is reserved exclusively for answering the OP question, to post comments or replies please use the comments section instead. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).